# How to make sense of MAC addresses of synology NAS cluster?

Tags: networking, nas, mac-address, failover

I'm using the following command to find out MAC addresses of the synology NAS cluster (two physical machines):

> arp -a

This shows me 4 different MAC addresses associated with the cluster. I assume two of them are for NAS and another two are for "load balancer" chip inside each one of the server, which enables failover functionality.

Can someone advice what would be the best way to understand which MAC address belongs to which physical server? It would also be great to know which ones belong to LB and which one is NAS.

Model number is: NS815+

Comment: I would imagine something like this is documented within the configuration page of the device

Comment: Tried that, the only place that I've found this information in DSM is Control Panel -> Network -> Bond 1 -> MAC address. But this only gives me a single MAC address, but arp -a gives me four ...

Comment: Have you tried to contact Synology?  If the MAC addresses are not obvious in that the adapter listed in the configuration is MAC Address A, and the first MAC address in the output of `arp -a` is MAC Address A then this likely will require somebody from Synology.  I know my Drobo lists both of its addresses for each interface it has.

Comment: Bond 1 indicates you have configured a single Bond across all 4 devices.  I doubt you will be exposed all 4 interfaces if you don't separate the Bond.  Your device has 4 ports, so all the 4 MAC addresses, each is connected to one of those ports.  `Main Menu -> System Information -> Network tab` should have it otherwise Synology Assistant should have it also.